# NodeJS Module build failed for thread-loader on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

Hi I am working on a NodeJS project on Visual Studio 2019  using npm. When I build the app it fails with following error

> - Building for production...          ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors20:53:01          error  in ./src/main.js        Module build failed (from
>     ./node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js):        Thread Loader (Worker 0)
>       [BABEL] C:\Projects\xxx\RedAir\redAir\src\main.js: .overrides
>     is not allowed in preset options
>           at PoolWorker.fromErrorObj (C:\Projects\xx\RedAir\redAir\node_modules\thread-loader\dist\WorkerPool.js:262:12)
>           at C:\Projects\xx\RedAir\redAir\node_modules\thread-loader\dist\WorkerPool.js:204:29
>           at mapSeries (C:\Projects\xx\RedAir\redAir\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:3625:14)
>           at Object.keys.forEach.key (C:\Projects\xx\RedAir\redAir\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\validation\options.js:71:13)
>           at Array.forEach ()
>           at validate (C:\Projects\xx\RedAir\redAir\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\validation\options.js:69:21)
>           at instantiatePreset (C:\Projects\xx\RedAir\redAir\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:242:36)
>           at cachedFunction (C:\Projects\xx\RedAir\redAir\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\caching.js:42:19)
>           at loadPresetDescriptor (C:\Projects\xx\RedAir\redAir\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:233:45)
>           at config.presets.map.descriptor (C:\Projects\xx\RedAir\redAir\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:68:19)
>           at Array.map ()
>           at recurseDescriptors (C:\Projects\xx\RedAir\redAir\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:66:38)
>           at loadFullConfig (C:\Projects\xx\RedAir\redAir\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:106:6)
>        @ multi ./src/main.js       ERROR  Build failed with errors.

Here is my **main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';

Vue.config.productionTip = true;

new Vue({
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

Here is **Package.json**

```
{
  "author": {
    "name": "HaBo"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime-corejs3": "^7.7.4",
    "@capacitor/core": "^1.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.25",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.11.2",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.8",
    "@ionic/core": "^4.11.5",
    "@ionic/vue": "0.0.4",
    "@openlayers/pepjs": "^0.5.3",
    "@sentry/browser": "^5.9.1",
    "@sentry/core": "^5.8.0",
    "@sentry/hub": "^5.8.0",
    "@sentry/integrations": "^5.8.0",
    "@sentry/minimal": "^5.8.0",
    "@sentry/types": "^5.7.1",
    "@sentry/utils": "^5.8.0",
    "@vue/babel-preset-app": "^4.1.1",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^3.2.0",
    "amazon-cognito-js": "^1.1.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.581.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "axios-extensions": "^3.0.6",
    "base64-js": "^1.3.1",
    "buffer": "^5.4.3",
    "core-js": "^3.4.5",
    "core-js-pure": "^3.4.5",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "d3": "^5.14.2",
    "d3-array": "^2.4.0",
    "d3-axis": "^1.0.12",
    "d3-brush": "^1.1.5",
    "d3-chord": "^1.0.6",
    "d3-collection": "^1.0.7",
    "d3-color": "^1.4.0",
    "d3-contour": "^1.3.2",
    "d3-dispatch": "^1.0.6",
    "d3-drag": "^1.2.5",
    "d3-dsv": "^1.2.0",
    "d3-ease": "^1.0.6",
    "d3-fetch": "^1.1.2",
    "d3-force": "^2.0.1",
    "d3-format": "^1.4.2",
    "d3-geo": "^1.11.9",
    "d3-hierarchy": "^1.1.9",
    "d3-interpolate": "^1.4.0",
    "d3-path": "^1.0.9",
    "d3-polygon": "^1.0.6",
    "d3-quadtree": "^1.0.7",
    "d3-random": "^2.0.1",
    "d3-scale": "^3.2.1",
    "d3-scale-chromatic": "^1.5.0",
    "d3-selection": "^1.4.1",
    "d3-shape": "^1.3.7",
    "d3-time": "^1.1.0",
    "d3-time-format": "^2.2.2",
    "d3-timer": "^1.0.10",
    "d3-tip": "^0.9.1",
    "d3-transition": "^1.3.2",
    "d3-voronoi": "^1.1.4",
    "d3-zoom": "^1.8.3",
    "dom7": "^2.1.3",
    "ieee754": "^1.1.13",
    "inherits": "^2.0.4",
    "ionicons": "^4.6.3",
    "is-buffer": "^2.0.4",
    "isarray": "^2.0.5",
    "jmespath": "^0.15.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.6.0",
    "leaflet-arc": "^1.0.2",
    "leaflet-easybutton": "^2.4.0",
    "line-clamp": "^1.0.0",
    "lru-cache": "^5.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.27",
    "node-libs-browser": "^2.2.1",
    "ol": "^6.1.1",
    "olcs": "^2.10.0",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "pseudomap": "^1.0.2",
    "q": "^1.5.1",
    "querystring-es3": "^0.2.1",
    "rbush": "^3.0.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.3",
    "secure-ls": "^1.2.5",
    "ssr-window": "^1.0.1",
    "swiper": "^5.2.1",
    "thread-loader": "^2.1.3",
    "three": "^0.111.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1",
    "util": "^0.12.1",
    "uuid": "^3.3.3",
    "vue-loader": "^15.7.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
    "vue-tour": "^1.1.0",
    "wicket": "^1.3.5",
    "yallist": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "description": "redAir",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "3.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "3.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-service": "3.0.4",
    "eslint": "5.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "4.7.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-template-compiler": "2.5.17"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "name": "red-air",
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0"
}
```

How do I overcome this issue and build it successfully?

Comment: any update on this? Stuck here right now

Comment: what's your nodejs version? and you were using `npm run build` for building the project?